# How does one deal with a cyclic dependency when coding DSP Signal Chains?

Tags: c, graph, filtering, signal-processing

I am looking into coding my own 3d audio rendering system as an educational project and because i have determined that technologies such as OpenAL are too device-oriented and feature lacking for my use.  I would like it to be as flexible as possible.  To that end, I have begun considering how I should go about coding it such that I can build signal chains from smaller pieces in programs that make use of it.  I can conceptually handle the case in which everything is just acyclic paths, but don't know what to do with cycles.  That is, how does one handle the case when an object depends on its current output sample to calculate its current output signal, either directly or indirectly?  The only two things I can think of are these: the program enters an infinite loop and crashes, or I artificially add latency when such dependencies occur.  Research turned up no information on this issue.

Comment: I am new to DSp.  Research failing to turn up information on this issue is likely because of a limited vocabulary.  I am not new to programming.  It would be nice to be able to pass a delay line through a filter and connect that filter back to the delay line, without having to add latency.  The alternative is of course to make multiple copies of the system and chain them, but this doesn't address the issue completely.  I do not wish to code anything until I've figured out this issue, because it will come up when I hit reverb, and a bit of thought now saves headaches later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

The technique you are looking for is called **Infinite Impulse Response (IIR) Filter**.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response

---

As you have suspected, a circular loop without any delay does not make much sense in terms of an impulse-response function.

<sub>*There are domains in which a circular loop without a delay would make sense. Those would be iterative systems. [Casuality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_filter) is also not an issue in those systems. Take the entire set of values A[index], pass that to a function, and get another set of values B[index]. A "transform" (such as discrete Fourier transform) would fit in that description. That would probably be far outside the scope of your project (or this discussion).*</sub>

---

Unit delays are often diagrammed as [image: (Z)^(-1)]. *(Refer to the diagram in the Wikipedia article for a correct rendering of that symbol.)*

This notation comes from [Z-transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform), a mathematical tool closely related to [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) and [Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform).

---

Roughly speaking,

- Laplace transform is used to analyze transient states of continuous-time systems
- Fourier transform is used to analyze:

  - Steady-state continuous-time systems
  - The frequency domain
  - Periodic systems
- Z-transform is used to analyze transient states of discrete time systems, such as the one you are working on.

---

The Stack Exchange network has a sister site for Digital Signal Processing at http://dsp.stackexchange.com

However, it is expected that newcomers to the DSP site have at least a basic understanding of DSP (roughly the equivalent of taking the first "Signals and Systems" course at the university level, or equivalent self-study.)

Hopefully you will gain a lot of knowledge from your project.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know all real-time audio software will either add latency or disallow feedback paths altogether.

It's well outside my area of knowledge but from my understanding electronic circuit simulators (Spice etc) take feedback into account. Perhaps you could see what techniques they use.